# isset выдает true для пустой строки

Tags: php, html

Разбираюсь с PHP и HTML, по книге "Робин Никсон CSS и HTML5". 
Видно издание немного отстало и возникают не большие проблемы. Большинство проблем я решаю, но в данном случае чего-то застрял...

Код:

```html
<?php
//test
if (isset($_POST['name'])) $name=$_POST['name'];
else $name="(not entered)";

echo <<<_END
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Your name is $name<br>
        <form method="post" action="test.php">
            What are your name?
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
_END;
```

При использовании `isset`, если `<input>` пустой, то условие `else $name="(not entered)"` не выполняется, чем можно заменить функцию `isset` что бы при учитывалось условие `else` при проверке поля ввода?

Я использую PHPStorm 9.0, ZendServer 6.3

Comment: С каким именем этот файл у вас на сервере лежит? Логи сервера что говоря?

Comment: `type="$name"` и `<htnm>`.

Comment: это из книги? там опечатки: htnm, from. Из-за последней и нет сабмита, html не знает что это форма (т.е. form) и куда надо сабмитить

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов  лежит с именем "test.php"

Comment: @Евгений, я же написал: правильно форму оформить надо, т.е. вместо `from` надо писать `form`, тогда будет сабмит работать. Если и появятся другие ошибки, то они уже не будут связанны с текущей

Comment: @ВОРОН  Я уже проверил и исправил, спасибо. Видно глаз не привык еще к коду.

Comment: Поправил код, теперь если поле ввода пустое, то не выполняется условие else $name="(not entered)";
Я скорректирую код в вопросе на верный что бы было видно код...

Comment: @Евгений, `isset` проверяет только определена ли переменная. Если `<input>` пустой, то переменная `$_POST['name']` определена и ее значение равно пустой строке. Так что ваш код делает все верно.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev может подскажите как, сделать так как я описал, что бы при отсутствии текста в `<input>`, срабатывало именно условие `else`?

Comment: @Евгений, задайте соответствующий вопрос, либо внесите изменения в текущий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструкция `isset` в PHP проверяет существует ли переменная (или элемент массива). При этом, эта переменная вполне может содержать пустую строку. В вашем случае, имеет смысл использовать `isset` с явной проверкой содержимого строки, например, так:

```
if (isset($a) && $a !== '') {
    // Переменная $a определена и не является пустой строкой.
} else {
    // Переменная $a - пустая.
}
```